# MSI Cache Protocol Pros and Cons

Tags: protocols

I have to make a step by step for the following two CPU 1 and 2. Which I did in the following excel sheet.

My two questions are:

1. Is it correct the state of CPU 2 is I (Invalid) in step 4.
2. What are the pros and cons of this protocol?

Where my current answer for question 2 is: "Pros are you can split the task up in two CPU's and cons is if the data is very dependent on each other this protocol is not useful."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: I thought this was important in c. What should it be tagged under then?

Comment: No idea, but there's literally no C code here.